# Overfitting and Data splitting

Tags: machine-learning

Let's say that I have a data file like:

Index,product_buying_date,col1,col2

0,2013-01-16,34,Jack

1,2013-01-12,43,Molly

2,2013-01-21,21,Adam

3,2014-01-09,54,Peirce

4,2014-01-17,38,Goldberg

5,2015-01-05,72,Chandler

..

..

2000000,2015-01-27,32,Mike

with some more data and I have a target variable y. Assume something as per your convenience.

Now I am aware that we divide the data into 2 parts i.e. Train and Test. And then we divide Train into 70:30, build the model with 70% and validate it with 30%. We tune the parameters so that model does not get overfit. And then predict with the Test data. For example: I divide 2000000 into two equal parts. 1000000 is train and I divide it in validate i.e. 30% of 1000000 which is 300000 and 70% is where I build the model i.e. 700000.

QUESTION: Is the above logic depending upon how the original data splits?

Generally we shuffle the data and then break it into train, validate and test. (train + validate = Train). (Please don't confuse here)
But what if the split is alternate. Like When I divide it in Train and Test first, I give even rows to Test and odd rows to Train. (Here data is initially sort on the basis of 'product_buying_date' column so when i split it in odd and even rows it gets uniformly split.

And when I build the model with Train I overfit it so that I get maximum AUC with Test data.

QUESTION: Isn't overfitting helping in this case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fits much better on http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ (and there is $math mode$ :-) ). Don't worry, you don't have to do anything. If enough people vote for this, the question will be moved automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QUESTION: Is the above logic depending upon how the original data
>   splits?

If dataset is large(hundred of thousand), you can randomly split the data and you should not have any problem but if dataset is small then you can adopt the different approaches like cross-validation to generate the data set. Cross-validation states that you split you make n number of training-validation set out of your Training set.

suppose you have 2000 data points, you split like

1000 - Training dataset

1000 - testing dataset.

5-cross validation would mean that you would make five 800/200 training/validation dataset.

> QUESTION: Isn't overfitting helping in this case?

Number one rule of the machine learning is that, you don't touch the test data set. It's a holly data set that should not be touched. 
If you overfit the test data to get maximum AUC score then there won't be any meaning of validation dataset. Foremost aim of any ml algorithm is to reduce the generalization error i.e. algorithm should be able to perform good on unseen data. If you would tune your algorithm with testing data. you won't be able to meet this criteria. **In cross-validation also you do not touch your testing set.** you select your algorithm. tune its parameter with validation dataset and after you have done with that apply your algorithm to test dataset which is your final score.